# Is there a most general "iterable" type accepted by Java for-each loops?

Tags: java

Is there a type `XXX<T>` that can be iterated on with for-each and subsumes both `T[]` and `Iterable<T>` so that the following compiles (assuming class context and a compatible method `do_something`) ?

```
public void iterate(XXX<T> items)
{
    for (T t : items)
        do_something(t);
}

public void iterate_array(T[] items)
{
    iterate(items);
}

public void iterate_iterable(Iterable<T> items)
{
    iterate(items);
}
```

In Java 1.5 I found nothing of the kind. Perhaps in a later version of the language ?
(I guess it's probably a FAQ. Sorry for the noise if it is. A quick google search did not give the answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: no, there is no type that covers both.

The simple solution is to wrap your array in a `List`, and then just invoke with that

```
public void iterate_array(T[] items)
{
    iterate(Arrays.asList(items));
}

public void iterate_array(Iterable<T> items)
{
    for (T t : items)
        do_something(t);    
}
```

Comment: Collections.asList should Arrays.asList, i think.

Comment: That certainly works.  How is that simpler than two methods that iterate over the array? Just copy and paste your second method and replace Iterable<t> with T[].  Your way seems to produce an object unnecessarily.

Comment: @emory: It's just a wrapper object, and object creation overhead is so cheap in a modern JVM to make it pointless to worry about it. Also, what if that iteration logic were 20 lines long? Would you still cut'n'paste it? Choosing to copy code rather than refactor it is a poor design choice.

Comment: Thanks skaffman. Indeed asList just creates a wrapper, not a copy, as I've verified reading doc & source.

Comment: @skaffman.  I assumed that the iteration logic was contained in a separate method - doSomething - in which case I would argue that directly iterating the array is both cleaner code and a micro-optimization.  However, if the iteration logic is directly in the for loop, then your approach is preferable.

Comment: @emory yes in my real code the logic is in the loop and there is logic around the loop as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to many other questions regarding arrays and generics. There is no supertype for arrays and iterables (other than object). And this is a problem because generics and arrays are not very compatible. Unless you need primitive arrays for performance reasons (doubt it), stick to generic collections.